# how to reduce transfer speed or latency

Tags: node.js, api, latency, low-latency

I've an API that takes about 5 to 6 seconds in latency. When in checked, I noticed that the database query execution completes in under 0.09 seconds. And then the NodeJS (Koa.js) function execution also completes immediately after that. However by the time the response reaches the client (browser or Postman) it has already consumed 5 to 6 seconds time.

I am trying to understand what has utilised this time. Please help me reduce this latency.

Comment: how long is the pieces of bytes which make up the string?

Comment: what type of data are you returning from the api call?

Comment: It's about 80000 lines of JSON (formatted) which is content-encoding:br, which is about 183kb during transfer and 1.3 mb at destination